# Django, problem with render request: "The view main.views.licz didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I'am trying to do a website and I have problem with uploading the file. On admin site I can upload and import any file but when I create view, I get this:
"The view main.views.licz didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."
Here is the code from main.models:

```
class Plik(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
```

Code from forms.py:

```
class upload(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

And code from views.py:

```
def licz(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = upload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("main/licz.html", {"form":form})
        else:
            form = Plik()
        return render(request, "main/licz.html", {"form":form})
```

Plz I am trying to solve this like 5 days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def licz(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = upload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("main/licz.html", {"form":form})
        else:
            form = Plik()
        return render(request, "main/licz.html", {"form":form})

    # if request is GET, python will execute this part of the function
```

Your `livz` function does not return anything on a `GET` request.
If no return statement is given, Python will return `None`.

The `return render(...)` is only executed on a `POST` request (when the form is submitted) with invalid form.

You need to also render your page on other request method.
A typical form view should look like the following (pay attention to the indent):

```
def form_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do stuff with the form
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success-url')
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return render('my-template', {'form': form})
```

Pay attention to your conditions (if/else/...) and make sure your page return a response in every possible path the code execution takes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def licz(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = upload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("main/licz.html")
        else:
            form = Plik()
    return render(request, "main/licz.html", {"form":form})
```